# How to limit the number of search results from table records using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to limit the number of search results from table records to 12 or any number less than 15 etc. This is how far I got with the code. What am i doing wrong?

I tried posting a JS Fiddle in Stack Overflow, but the code is just too long to post.

I prepared a Js Fiddle for better understanding.

Jquery part alone below:

```
 $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
 var value = $(this).val();
 $("table tr").each(function(index) {
 if (index !== 0) {
    $row = $(this);
    $row.find('td').each (function() {
        var id = $(this).text();
        if (this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== 0) {

            $row.slice(0,12).hide();
        }
        else {
            $row.slice(0,12).show();
            return false;
        }
    });  

}
 });
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle link which i prepared for better understanding.

https://jsfiddle.net/5g3yxrz4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5g3yxrz4/5/

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
var value = $(this).val();
var showRowsLimit = 12;
var rowsShowing = 0;
$("table tr").each(function(index) {
    if (index !== 0) {
        $row = $(this);
        $row.find('td').each (function() {
            var id = $(this).text();
            if (this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== 0 || rowsShowing>=showRowsLimit) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
                rowsShowing++;
                return false;
            }
        });  
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
const max = 12; // Maximum to show
...
var i = 0;
...
else if(i++ < max) {
...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5g3yxrz4/3/

Just added counter for showed "tr"

Comment: if the search box is empty all the table results show up. This shouldn't happen. This is the mistake im getting. If the searchbox is empty, the results should also be 12 which is the max value.